# IPv4 Subnetting - Finding IDs for specific subnets

Tags: networking, subnet, ipv4

I need to know how to calculate/find the network ID for a specific subnet. For example, if we need 1000 subnets and 35 usable hosts, how do I find the subnet ID for the 250th subnet? Also, how do I know the range of usable hosts? Let's say the network address is 183.67.0.0, Class B, and Default subnet is 255.255.0.0.

Comment: This looks very much like a homework question... and address classes and "default" subnet masks have been obsolete for _decades_, so whatever study material you have, it is not good.

Comment: sometimes people get unproductively sanctimonious about cidr... we're talking about subnetting so VLSM is implied. Op, the question you have asked is fundamental to IP, so read this: https://www.dnsstuff.com/subnet-ip-subnetting-guide Also, as general advise, binary is the best expression to learn about how IP address/mask's work together. it is helpful to understand how the patterns of bits change as the mask does, and the people who conceived of IPv4 expected all its practitioners to understand the nature of binary numbers well.

Answer (score 2):

No one really answered this and I spent about an hour last night frantically searching for one because I *also* had this as a homework question. Since the first network will always be all zeroes in binary, to get the 250th subnet ID you would just need to insert 249 in binary into your subnet table. It would end up looking something like `183.67.00111110.01|000000`. The pipe would represent the amount of bits you'd be borrowing, in this case it's 10. The 250th subnet ID would be `183.67.62.64`.

Answer (score 0):

[Online Subnet Calculator](http://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html)

I think this is doing what you are looking for. Just calculate a subnet and then you receive all the matching subnets in the results.